# Error when accessing EJB local interface in POJO

Tags: java, servlets, ejb

I have an ear file and inside this ear there is war for my webapplication .
Now I have a requirement to lookup a local interface of an EJB through a POJO (this is a scriptlet which is used in jasperreports).

The EJB which I want to use has two jars (this are third party api)
One service interface jar having local interface defined in it and other implementation class 
The interface jar name is say : xyz-interface.jar 
and implementation jar name is say xyz.jar

Now In my ear generation pom.xml i have done following configuration

```
     <ejbModule>
 <groupId>parentpackage</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
<bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
</ejbModule>

   <jarModule>
<groupId>parentpackage</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz-interface</artifactId>
<bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>                      
</jarModule>


          <dependency>
        <groupId>parentpackage</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
        <version>${cdmr.version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


In the web.xml My configuration is like

<ejb-local-ref>
<ejb-ref-name>ejb/local/xyzEJB</ejb-ref-name>
<ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
<local>package.xyz</local>
<ejb-link>xyzEJB</ejb-link>
```

Comment: Now in the code I using initialcontext I am trying to lookup this EJB using its local interface

 

    public static final UnitsOfMeasureService getUnitOfMeasureServiceEJB() throws
    NamingException
      {
          return(UnitsOfMeasureService) getInitialContext().lookup(env/ejb/local/xyzEJB");
      }

Comment: but when deploying the code I am getting exception as 

    Error: The ejb-link 'xyzEJB' declared in the ejb-ref or 
    ejb-local-ref 'ejb/local/UnitsOfMeasureServiceEJB' in the application module 
    'jasperserver-war.war' could not be resolved.

Comment: You should edit your question and add any additional details/code to it instead of adding comments - it would be more readable... especially for the code.

Comment: What pplication server do you use?